# TravelingTournament MatchChainRotationsMoveFactory

Tags: optaplanner

I know the examples suggest avoiding the "old, complex, tailored example" [Traveling Tournament](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.8.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#travelingTournament), but this is very near perfect for my needs.

I am trying to fully understand the logic in MatchChainRotationsMoveFactory and wonder if there is any online documentation or additional details about the implementation of this particular MoveFactory.

Short of that, and aside from the online OptaPlanner documentation are there recommended resources for getting smart on custom MoveFatory's.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the MatchChainRotationsMoveFactory picks a random match A and moves that to a random day D1. Match A has 2 teams: T1 and T2. Then it looks for T2's match on day D1 and moves that to avoid T2 having 2 matches on the same day. That is match B. Wherever that match B ends up, it again needs to fix the other's team side, leading to match C. And so forth, until it ends up back with match A and close the loop hole.

This move avoids breaking the hard constraint "only 1 match per day".